# How to extract the loudest fragment from MP3 with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an mp3 file and want to extract the loudest (RMS) fragment (e.g. 10 seconds long). How do I do this with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is only a partial soulution. But to get a table of time vs. volume in 0.1s fragments, use this:

```
ffmpeg -nostats -i audio.mp3 -filter_complex ebur128=peak=true -f null - 2>&1 |\
grep -oE ' t: [^ ]+| FTPK: +.[^ ]+' |\
paste - - > volume_profile.txt
```

Then use that table to calculate all RMS of in a loop (I'd suggest FORTRAN for this task) and pick the proper interval. Back to `ffmpeg` with this start and end times.